# Exclude constructor from obfuscation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

There is ObfuscationAttibute in .NET. But I don't understand, how to exclude code inside constructor from obfuscation.

```
// Obfuscated class
class MyClass {
    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)] // "Attribute 'Obfuscation' is not valid on this declaration type"
    public MyClass() {
        //some code, I need to exclude this code from obfuscation
    }
    // Obfuscated method
    public void Method1() {
        //some code
    |
    // Obfuscated method
    public void Method2() {
        //some code
    |
}
```

UPD: The question is NOT about renaming constructor. It's name obviously became ".ctor". I need to prevent obfuscation of code itself. Yes, some obfuscators not only rename symbols, but change code, too. Yes, I know I can't do it with this attribute. Compiler says the same. I already know what I cannot do. I am asking what i can do, prefferably using only standard .net instruments.

Comment: The `ObfuscationAttribute` does not include `AttributeTargets.Constructor` as a valid usage for the attribute... so it is not possible.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, and the question is how to walkaround it, preferrably, using builtin .net instruments.

Comment: A constructor's name is not something you or the obfuscator can choose. In C#, the constructor name is just the same as the containing type's name. In the IL, the constructor name is always `.ctor` (non-static) or `.cctor` (static constructor, a.k.a. type initializer). What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a constructor to look like a regular method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do what you want using only `ObfuscationAttribute`, but it's tedious: apply `[Obfuscation(ApplyToMembers=false)]` to the class, and `[Obfuscation]` to every individual member *except* the constructor.

Alternatively, use your obfuscator's configuration to exclude the constructor from consideration. Since `ObfuscationAttribute` offers only very limited control (just turning features on and off, basically) most have separate configuration for fine-grained control.

Finally, consider making your constructor so simple and uninteresting that it doesn't matter if the flow is obfuscated or not. This should ideally be the case anyway -- if your constructor only performs member initialization, there isn't much to obfuscate in the first place. You can call member functions for the more involved stuff, and you can control obfuscation of those using the attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Constructors are always renamed to `.ctor` internally, you can't use an obfuscated name (but you can't use the original name either).  And decompilers will name the constructor with the obfuscated class name.

I suppose you mean obfuscation of the code inside the function, not the member name?  Presumably a more advanced obfuscator that supports code rearrangement and not just name obfuscation will have its own attribute to control that... because `System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute` isn't suitable for control of more powerful obfuscation techniques.

In particular, the `AttributeUsageAttribute` on the `ObfuscationAttribute` class doesn't include `AttributeTargets.Constructor` as an allowed usage.

Comment: The lack of applicability to constructors seems to be an oversight based on the assumption that it only indicates renaming, even though `ObfuscationAttribute` has a `Feature` property for more fine-grained control over obfuscation. This is used by (e.g.) Dotfuscator to indicate "do not rename this (but do obfuscate flow)", which would certainly make sense for a constructor.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Given the rename-oriented nature of the attribute, seems like Dotfuscator would be better served by providing their own custom attribute to control flow obfuscation.

Comment: It's worth nothing that [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute) does not use the word "rename" anywhere. It's careful to describe obfuscation in terms of "features". If they went to that trouble, they might as well have acknowledged that there are obfuscation features that apply to constructors... but, of course, since renaming is the most *prominent* obfuscation feature, it's an understandable oversight.

Answer (score 2):

I very much agree with the comments noting that obfuscation is not all about renaming, and it does seem to be an oversight that constructors were not considered a valid target for `[Obfuscation]`. I have run into the problem with dead code removal, where the obfuscator can remove code that is not reachable (I'm simplifying). Overriding this behaviour is sometimes necessary, for example for reflection/serialization scenarios, and can equally apply to constructors as much as any other code element. Note that `[AttributeUsage]` is only advisory, and is enforced by the C# (or VB) compiler. It is not enforced by the CLR. So if your obfuscator is designed to look for `[Obfuscation]` on constructors (which might well be the case by accident given that some obfuscator logic might treat all methods equally), and you can use some kind of post-compilation IL processing framework (eg, PostSharp), then you can put `[Obfuscation]` onto constructors. For PostSharp users, here is a multicast version of `ObfuscationAttribute` that will happily apply `[Obfuscation]` to constructors:

```
using System;
using PostSharp.Aspects;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;
using PostSharp.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

/// <summary>
/// A multicast adapter for <see cref="ObfuscationAttribute"/>. Instructs obfuscation tools to take the specified actions for the target assembly, type, or member.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Struct | AttributeTargets.Enum | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Event | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Delegate | AttributeTargets.Constructor, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false )]
[MulticastAttributeUsage( 
    MulticastTargets.Assembly | MulticastTargets.Class | MulticastTargets.Struct | MulticastTargets.Enum | MulticastTargets.Method | MulticastTargets.Property | MulticastTargets.Field | MulticastTargets.Event | MulticastTargets.Interface | MulticastTargets.Parameter | MulticastTargets.Delegate | MulticastTargets.InstanceConstructor | MulticastTargets.InstanceConstructor,
    AllowMultiple = true,
    PersistMetaData = false)]
public sealed class MulticastObfuscationAttribute : MulticastAttribute, IAspectProvider
{
    bool _stripAfterObfuscation = true;
    bool _exclude = true;
    bool _applyToMembers = true;
    string _feature = "all";

    bool _stripAfterObfuscationIsSpecified;
    bool _excludeIsSpecified;
    bool _applyToMembersIsSpecified;
    bool _featureIsSpecified;

    static readonly ConstructorInfo ObfuscationAttributeCtor = typeof( ObfuscationAttribute ).GetConstructor( Type.EmptyTypes );

    IEnumerable<AspectInstance> IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects( object targetElement )
    {
        var oc = new ObjectConstruction( ObfuscationAttributeCtor );

        if ( _applyToMembersIsSpecified )
            oc.NamedArguments[ nameof( ObfuscationAttribute.ApplyToMembers ) ] = _applyToMembers;

        if ( _excludeIsSpecified )
            oc.NamedArguments[ nameof( ObfuscationAttribute.Exclude ) ] = _exclude;

        if ( _featureIsSpecified )
            oc.NamedArguments[ nameof( ObfuscationAttribute.Feature ) ] = _feature;

        if ( _stripAfterObfuscationIsSpecified )
            oc.NamedArguments[ nameof( ObfuscationAttribute.StripAfterObfuscation ) ] = _stripAfterObfuscation;

        return new[] { new AspectInstance( targetElement, new CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect( oc ) ) };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <see cref="T:System.Boolean" /> value indicating whether the obfuscation tool should remove this attribute after processing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// <see langword="true" /> if an obfuscation tool should remove the attribute after processing; otherwise, <see langword="false" />. The default is <see langword="true" />.
    /// </returns>
    public bool StripAfterObfuscation
    {
        get => _stripAfterObfuscation;
        set
        {
            _stripAfterObfuscationIsSpecified = true;
            _stripAfterObfuscation = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <see cref="T:System.Boolean" /> value indicating whether the obfuscation tool should exclude the type or member from obfuscation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// <see langword="true" /> if the type or member to which this attribute is applied should be excluded from obfuscation; otherwise, <see langword="false" />. The default is <see langword="true" />.
    /// </returns>
    public bool Exclude
    {
        get => _exclude;
        set
        {
            _excludeIsSpecified = true;
            _exclude = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a <see cref="T:System.Boolean" /> value indicating whether the attribute of a type is to apply to the members of the type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// <see langword="true" /> if the attribute is to apply to the members of the type; otherwise, <see langword="false" />. The default is <see langword="true" />.
    /// </returns>
    public bool ApplyToMembers
    {
        get => _applyToMembers;
        set
        {
            _applyToMembersIsSpecified = true;
            _applyToMembers = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a string value that is recognized by the obfuscation tool, and which specifies processing options.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A string value that is recognized by the obfuscation tool, and which specifies processing options. The default is "all".
    /// </returns>
    public string Feature
    {
        get => _feature;
        set
        {
            _featureIsSpecified = true;
            _feature = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Why [ObfuscationAttribute] is not allowed on constructors

You can't put [`[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.obfuscationattribute) onto a constructor because obfuscation **renames symbols**, not the **contents** of methods *(usually - more advanced obfuscators can change the flow of code, modify constants, etc. to make reverse-engineering harder)*.

For example, consider the following:

```
// obfuscated class
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }
}

// unobfuscated class
public class CallingClass
{
    public static void TestMyClass()
    {
        MyClass class = new MyClass();
        class.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

The obfuscator would rename `MyClass` to something else (e.g. `qfghjigffvvb`) and `MyMethod()` to something else (e.g. `ghjbvxdghh()`) and change all references so that the code still works the same, i.e.

```
public class qfghjigffvvb
{
    public qfghjigffvvb()
    {
    }

    public void ghjbvxdghh()
    {
    }
}

// unobfuscated class
public class CallingClass
{
    public static void TestMyClass()
    {
        qfghjigffvvb class = new qfghjigffvvb();
        class.ghjbvxdghh();
    }
}
```

If you put the `[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]` attribute onto the constructor for `MyClass`, then `CallingClass.TestMyClass()` would look like this:

```
public class CallingClass
{
    public static void TestMyClass()
    {
        qfghjigffvvb class = new MyClass(); // ?
        class.ghjbvxdghh();
    }
}
```

If you need the *contents* of the `MyClass` constructor to not be obfuscated, you'd need to put the `[Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]` attribute onto everything that it calls so that the symbols won't be renamed.

---

### Thought experiment: excluding the contents of the constructor

Say you had a `[ContentObfuscation]` attribute which you could use to stop the *contents* of a method (or constructor or property) from being obfuscated. What would you want it to do here?

```
public class MyClass
{
    [ContentObfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public MyClass()
    {
        // SecurityCriticalClass is obfuscated
        var securityCriticalClass = new SecurityCriticalClass();
        securityCriticalClass.DoSomeTopSecretStuff();
    }
}
```

If the *contents* of the constructor are not obfuscated, then `SecurityCriticalClass` would also have to be not obfuscated, possibly creating a security issue.